# Find the area of that part of the surface of the sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=a^2$ cut out by the cilinder $\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2} = 1$

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

This is exercise 46 from Piskunov Chapter 14

Find the area of that part of the surface of the sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=a^2$ cut out by the cilinder $\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2} = 1 \text{ , } a>b $

First, I parametrized the sphere using the function:

$g(x,y)=(x,y,\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2})$

and then I used the next set as the domain of integration:

$ D=\{ (x,y) \in  \mathbb R^2 : 0\leq x\leq a \text { ,  } 0\leq y \leq \sqrt{b^2- \frac{ b^2x^2}{a^2 }}\}$

then I simply used the formula

$S=\int_D \sqrt{1+\left(\frac{dz}{dx}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{dz}{dy}\right)^2}= \int_{ 0 }^a\int_0^{ \sqrt{b^2- \frac{ b^2x^2}{a^2 }}} \sqrt{ \frac{a^2 }{a^2-x^2-y^2 } }dydx $

is this right? I thought about changing to polar coordinates, but I still can't get to solve the integral. The answers supposed to be $4\pi a^2-8a^2-Arcsin(\frac{ \sqrt{a^2-b^2}}   {a})$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Compute the area of that part of the surface of the sphere $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = a^2$ cut out by the surface $\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2} = 1$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1825205/compute-the-area-of-that-part-of-the-surface-of-the-sphere-x2-y2-z2-a)

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1756517/surface-of-sphere-above-below-ellipse?noredirect=1